# simple cast from interface method result to integer

Tags: c#, casting

I have interface IBookRepository. That interface has method CountAllBooks() which returns integer. 
If I inside method receiving value of type object

```
public object Convert(object value)
```

and if that passed object is of type IBookRepository why I cannot cast it's CountAllBooks result as integer like

```
public object Convert(object value)
{
   int c;
   if(value is IBookRepository)
   {
      c = (int)value.CountAllBooks();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public object Convert(object value)
{ 
   int c;
   if(value is IBookRepository)
   {
      c = (int)((IBookRepository)value).CountAllBooks();
   }
   return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public object Convert(object value)
{
   int c;
   if(value is IBookRepository)
   {
      c = (int)(value as IBookRepository).CountAllBooks(); //casting "object" to "IBookRepository"
   }
}
```